# Using WPDB to connect to external database for inserting dynamic form data with php

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic-forms

I have an external database where I want my form data to be inserted to with $wpdb. On the page where the form resides, I am able to declare $wpdb as a global and then do a newdb to pull results and echo them into my form.

This code currently works:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$member_id = SwpmMemberUtils::get_logged_in_members_id();
$field_name = 'user_name';
$fname_value = SwpmMemberUtils::get_member_field_by_id($member_id, $field_name); 

    $newdb = new wpdb( 'user' , 'pass' , 'database' , 'localhost' );
    $newdb->show_errors();
$results = $newdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM member_lists WHERE username = %s",$fname_value));
?>
```

For the submit form action, I have a PHP file named update-list.php that I have in my theme child folder to do the insert for my post data which is not working. I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'wpdb' not found in /home/site/www/www/home/wp-content/themes/Avada-child/update-list.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/site/www/www/home/wp-content/themes/Avada-child/update-list.php on line 4

Here is the code for that update-list.php file:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$newdb = new wpdb( 'user' , 'pass' , 'database' , 'localhost' );

$stats = array();
for( $i = 0; $i <= $stats; $i++ ) 
{
    $stats[] = array(
        'username' => $_POST['username'],
        'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
        'county' => $_POST['county'],
        'street' => $_POST['street'],
        'city' => $_POST['city'],
        'ward' => $_POST['precinct'], 
    );
}

foreach ( $stats as $stat )
    $newdb=$wpdb->insert( 'member_lists', $stat );


?>
```

Why does it recognize wpdb on the page with my form but not in the form action update-list.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something you should be [Using AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for (which would eliminate the issue at hand).

With that said, your issue as it stands is because you're POSTing to essentially an *arbitrary PHP file* that has **no knowledge of WordPress**. Since it wasn't loaded into the request with WordPress methods, you'll need to load up WordPress yourself. Take a look at [this WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files).

Basically, at a minimum, you'll need to add `require_once '/path/to/your/wp-load.php';` at the top of your `update-list.php` file before you can use anything 'WordPress', including `$wpdb`.